# HTML select not refreshing after being populated via JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

I've been using JQuery to populate a drop down list on the click of a HTML select element.  The options get created however on the first click the options get shown in a very small box with a scroll.  see below

[incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAVho.png)

If I then close and reopen the dropdown it appears correctly. as below.

[correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTYgq.png)

It feels like the dropdown list is appearing before jquery has rendered the new options elements.  I've tried to find away to re-render it but with no luck.

This feels like it should be such an easy fix but I'm new to scripting and struggling.

HTML

```
<select class="custom-select" id="templateGroupName" name="templateGroupName">
    <option selected>Please Select a group</option>
</select>
```

JS - Wrapped in document.ready

```
$('#templateGroupName').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/Layout/GetGroups',
        success: function (data) {
            helpers.buildDropdown(
                data,
                $('#templateGroupName'),
                'Select an option'
            );
        }
    });

});

var helpers =
{
    buildDropdown: function (result, dropdown, emptyMessage) {
        // Remove current options
        dropdown.html('');
        // Add the empty option with the empty message
        dropdown.append('<option value="">' + emptyMessage + '</option>');
        // Check result isnt empty
        if (result != '') {
            // Loop through each of the results and append the option to the dropdown
            $.each(result, function (k, v) {
                dropdown.append('<option value="' + v.Id + '">' + v.Name + '</option>');
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: because you are adding them asynchronously...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser gets confused when you inject options while the `<select>` is open. To be fair, your users would probably be confused too.

If you're waiting for something to load, *tell them to wait*.
If something isn't usable, *disable it*.

Putting these two together: the **first** time a user hovers over the `<select>`, disable it and set the cursor to a loading wheel. Wait until your data loads, then insert the options, re-enable it and switch the cursor back.

```js
var helpers = {
  buildDropdown: function(result, dropdown, emptyMessage) {
    dropdown.html('');
    dropdown.append(`<option value="">${emptyMessage}</option>`);
    if (!!result) {
      $.each(result, function(k, v) {
        dropdown.append(`
            <option value="${v.Id}">
              ${v.Name}
            </option>
         `);
      });
    }
  }
}

const $DROPDOWN = $('#templateGroupName');
// using jQuery#one to only fire the click event once
$DROPDOWN.one('mouseenter', _ => {
  // disable dropdown while loading options
  $DROPDOWN.attr('disabled', true)
  console.log('loading options...');
  // replace contents with your GET request
  setTimeout(function() {
    helpers.buildDropdown(
      Array.from({
        length: 30
      }, (_, i) => ({
        Id: i,
        Name: i
      })),
      $DROPDOWN,
      'Select an option'
    );
    // un-disable after options are loaded and inserted
    $DROPDOWN.attr('disabled', false)
  }, 1000);
})
```

```css
/* Show "loading" wheel while loading */

select.custom-select[disabled] {
  cursor: wait;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="custom-select" id="templateGroupName" name="templateGroupName">
  <option selected>Please Select a group</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need a `<select>` as the parent, not an empty element,

```
dropdown = $('#templateGroupName');
```

then insert it as a document element, not a string:

```
var opt = document.createElement('option');
opt.value = v.Id;
opt.innerHTML = v.Name;
dropdown.appendChild(opt);
```